# function handleNewMessages does not want to run

Tags: c++, iot, esp32, arduino-ide, arduino-esp32

I have this code for ESP32CAM, for arduino ide.
This program takes photos every 16 minutes and sends them to telegram automatically.
I wanted that when I write the /photo command in telegram, the camera will take a photo and when I write the /flash command, it will turn on the flash.
These 2 things are the ones that don't work for me.

The program does take the photo every 16 minutes, but it doesn't want to run the commands.

This is the code:

```
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <WiFi.h>
#include <WiFiClientSecure.h>
#include "soc/soc.h"
#include "soc/rtc_cntl_reg.h"
#include "esp_camera.h"
#include <UniversalTelegramBot.h>
#include <ArduinoJson.h>

const char* ssid = "xxxxxxxx";
const char* password = "xxxxxxxx";

// Initialize Telegram BOT
String BOTtoken = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";  // your Bot Token 

String CHAT_ID = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";

WiFiClientSecure clientTCP;
UniversalTelegramBot bot(BOTtoken, clientTCP);

#define FLASH_LED_PIN 4
bool flashState = LOW;

//Checks for new messages every 1 second.
int botRequestDelay = 1000;
unsigned long lastTimeBotRan;

//CAMERA_MODEL_AI_THINKER
#define PWDN_GPIO_NUM     32
#define RESET_GPIO_NUM    -1
#define XCLK_GPIO_NUM      0
#define SIOD_GPIO_NUM     26
#define SIOC_GPIO_NUM     27

#define Y9_GPIO_NUM       35
#define Y8_GPIO_NUM       34
#define Y7_GPIO_NUM       39
#define Y6_GPIO_NUM       36
#define Y5_GPIO_NUM       21
#define Y4_GPIO_NUM       19
#define Y3_GPIO_NUM        18
#define Y2_GPIO_NUM        5
#define VSYNC_GPIO_NUM    25
#define HREF_GPIO_NUM     23
#define PCLK_GPIO_NUM     22

unsigned long previousMillis = 0;
const unsigned long interval = 960000; // 16 minutes
bool sendPhoto = false; 

void configInitCamera(){
  pinMode(FLASH_LED_PIN, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(FLASH_LED_PIN, flashState);
  
  camera_config_t config;
  config.ledc_channel = LEDC_CHANNEL_0;
  config.ledc_timer = LEDC_TIMER_0;
  config.pin_d0 = Y2_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_d1 = Y3_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_d2 = Y4_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_d3 = Y5_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_d4 = Y6_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_d5 = Y7_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_d6 = Y8_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_d7 = Y9_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_xclk = XCLK_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_pclk = PCLK_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_vsync = VSYNC_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_href = HREF_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_sscb_sda = SIOD_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_sscb_scl = SIOC_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_pwdn = PWDN_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_reset = RESET_GPIO_NUM;
  config.xclk_freq_hz = 20000000;
  config.pixel_format = PIXFORMAT_JPEG;

  //init with high specs to pre-allocate larger buffers
  if(psramFound()){
    config.frame_size = FRAMESIZE_UXGA;
    config.jpeg_quality = 10;  //0-63 lower number means higher quality
    config.fb_count = 2;
  } else {
    config.frame_size = FRAMESIZE_SVGA;
    config.jpeg_quality = 12;  //0-63 lower number means higher quality
    config.fb_count = 1;
  }

  // camera init
  esp_err_t err = esp_camera_init(&config);
  if (err != ESP_OK) {
    Serial.printf("Camera init failed with error 0x%x", err);
    delay(1000);
    ESP.restart();
  }

  // Drop down frame size for higher initial frame rate
  sensor_t * s = esp_camera_sensor_get();
  s->set_framesize(s, FRAMESIZE_CIF);  // UXGA|SXGA|XGA|SVGA|VGA|CIF|QVGA|HQVGA|QQVGA
}

void handleNewMessages(int numNewMessages) {
  Serial.print("Handle New Messages: ");
  Serial.println(numNewMessages);

  for (int i = 0; i < numNewMessages; i++) {
    String chat_id = String(bot.messages[i].chat_id);
    if (chat_id != CHAT_ID){
      bot.sendMessage(chat_id, "Unauthorized user", "");
      continue;
    }
    
    // Print the received message
    String text = bot.messages[i].text;
    Serial.println(text);
    
    String from_name = bot.messages[i].from_name;
    if (text == "/start") {
      String welcome = "Welcome , " + from_name + "\n";
      welcome += "Use the following commands to interact with the ESP32-CAM \n";
      welcome += "/photo : takes a new photo\n";
      welcome += "/flash : toggles flash LED \n";
      bot.sendMessage(CHAT_ID, welcome, "");
    }
    if (text == "/flash") {
      flashState = !flashState;
      digitalWrite(FLASH_LED_PIN, flashState);
      Serial.println("Change flash LED state");
    }
    if (text == "/photo") {
      sendPhoto = true;
      Serial.println("New photo request");
    }
  }
}

String sendPhotoTelegram() {
  const char* myDomain = "api.telegram.org";
  String getAll = "";
  String getBody = "";

  camera_fb_t * fb = NULL;
  fb = esp_camera_fb_get();  
  if(!fb) {
    Serial.println("Camera capture failed");
    delay(1000);
    ESP.restart();
    return "Camera capture failed";
  }  
  
  Serial.println("Connect to " + String(myDomain));


  if (clientTCP.connect(myDomain, 443)) {
    Serial.println("Connection successful");
    
    String head = "--Electro\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"chat_id\"; \r\n\r\n" + CHAT_ID + "\r\n--Electro\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"photo\"; filename=\"esp32-cam.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n";
    String tail = "\r\n--Electro--\r\n";

    uint16_t imageLen = fb->len;
    uint16_t extraLen = head.length() + tail.length();
    uint16_t totalLen = imageLen + extraLen;
  
    clientTCP.println("POST /bot"+BOTtoken+"/sendPhoto HTTP/1.1");
    clientTCP.println("Host: " + String(myDomain));
    clientTCP.println("Content-Length: " + String(totalLen));
    clientTCP.println("Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=Electro");
    clientTCP.println();
    clientTCP.print(head);
  
    uint8_t *fbBuf = fb->buf;
    size_t fbLen = fb->len;
    for (size_t n=0;n<fbLen;n=n+1024) {
      if (n+1024<fbLen) {
        clientTCP.write(fbBuf, 1024);
        fbBuf += 1024;
      }
      else if (fbLen%1024>0) {
        size_t remainder = fbLen%1024;
        clientTCP.write(fbBuf, remainder);
      }
    }  
    
    clientTCP.print(tail);
    
    esp_camera_fb_return(fb);
    
    int waitTime = 10000;   // timeout 10 seconds
    long startTimer = millis();
    boolean state = false;
    
    while ((startTimer + waitTime) > millis()){
      Serial.print(".");
      delay(100);      
      while (clientTCP.available()) {
        char c = clientTCP.read();
        if (state==true) getBody += String(c);        
        if (c == '\n') {
          if (getAll.length()==0) state=true; 
          getAll = "";
        } 
        else if (c != '\r')
          getAll += String(c);
        startTimer = millis();
      }
      if (getBody.length()>0) break;
    }
    clientTCP.stop();
    Serial.println(getBody);
  }
  else {
    getBody="Connected to api.telegram.org failed.";
    Serial.println("Connected to api.telegram.org failed.");
  }
  return getBody;
}

void setup(){
  WRITE_PERI_REG(RTC_CNTL_BROWN_OUT_REG, 0); 
  // Init Serial Monitor
  Serial.begin(115200);

  // Set LED Flash as output
  pinMode(FLASH_LED_PIN, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(FLASH_LED_PIN, flashState);

  // Config and init the camera
  configInitCamera();

  // Connect to Wi-Fi
  WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);
  Serial.println();
  Serial.print("Connecting to ");
  Serial.println(ssid);
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
  clientTCP.setCACert(TELEGRAM_CERTIFICATE_ROOT); // Add root certificate for api.telegram.org
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    Serial.print(".");
    delay(500);
  }
  Serial.println();
  Serial.print("ESP32-CAM IP Address: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP()); 
}

void loop() {
  unsigned long currentMillis = millis();

  // Toma una foto cada 16 minutos o cuando se reciba el comando /photo
  if (currentMillis - previousMillis >= interval || sendPhoto) {
    previousMillis = currentMillis;
    sendPhoto = false;

    // Envía la foto
    String photo = sendPhotoTelegram();
    bot.sendPhoto(CHAT_ID, photo, "");
    Serial.println("New photo request");
  }

  // Maneja nuevos mensajes
  int numNewMessages = bot.getUpdates(botRequestDelay);
  handleNewMessages(numNewMessages);
}
```

Comment: Whatever `text` you received, it probably not exactly is `text == "/flash"`. Find the String [methods](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/variables/data-types/stringobject/) that can do the job, maybe `String.indexof()` or `String.substring()`.